# How to parse xml data using multiple nodes in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse xml using different parent nodes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775812/how-to-parse-xml-using-different-parent-nodes-in-android)

I am making an application in which i have to parse xml data, and i have made that, but i am using only single node in my xml file like, but the thing is now i want to add one more node in my xml file namely, and attributes in both the nodes would be same, and i am using this code, so please let me know what are the changes required to add  node in same program, because i want whenever user will click on listview item node row then only data related to should be shown in next activity, and vice-versa :-

```
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
```

Comment: How should we know how your parser looks like? What Kind of parser are you using? Pull - SAX or DOM parser?

Comment: see this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/ (Similar to this link), but also want to add videos node in xml file

Comment: i am using dom parser, see this link:-http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/     what are the changes i need to do in java class

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file add a tag

```
<video>YOUR CONTENT HERE</video>
```

under every

```
<title>
```

tag. If you are using the androidhive.com's xml file you will need to download it and then modify it using a program like Notepad++ and the upload it onto a server like the public folder in dropbox, or a FTP server or even local host on your computer.

---

**Changes in JAVA Class**

- Add KEY_VIDEO under the other String Variables (KEY_ARTIST, KEY_TITLE, etc)
- Add map.put(KEY_VIDEO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VIDEO));

*If you require it to be displayed in the list view open the lazy adapter and add this:

- TextView video = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.video); <----- You need to add a text view with this id in the layout (R.layout.listrow)
- video.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_VIDEO));

---

**EDIT**

I misunderstood, disregard the above

if you are adding another

```
<video>
```

tag like the

```
<music>
```

tag all you have to do is change this one line.

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_VIDEO);
```

Comment: what are the changes i need to do in java class, because still i am using these lines of code:-  static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";              but i also want to add videos node with similar attributes as in song...

Comment: If this is the right answer mark it as correct so that other users with the same problem can find help

Comment: thanks to help, useful, but i want to use multiple nodes in a single java class, so how can i write code for all in a java class, i think like this:-  // parent node song
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node videos
    static final String KEY_SONG = "videos";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title"; and       NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_VIDEOS);
        Please let me know am i doing wrong or right, Thanks Again

Comment: How are you going to know wether to parse songs or videos?

Comment: Probably something like if {CODE HERE TO DETERMINE WHICH ONE TO USE} KEY_NODE = "song" else KEY_NODE = "video"

Comment: Like:- i have two xml files, first to get the list of nodes in listview item, example: music, videos, movies and second xml file to get the selected node items in another activity if user will click on videos listview node row then another activity will open with only those data that related to videos node not related to song or movies, is it possible to call and if yes so please how it could be possible...

Comment: @user1350766 So to confirm you have 2 different xml files?

Comment: Squires i have two xml files, in one of them i am using to get the list of meus namely pizza, burger and so on and other xml file i am using to get the list of items under pizza, list of items under burger, so in my second xml file from which i am getting list of items i am using pizza and burger as a parent node and attributes in both nodes are same with name, and i am using only single xml file for all the list item nodes and now i need to fetch data that related to particular node only which user has selected in listivew, no problem if you want to clear some more things i am open for it...

Comment: I would reccomend using JSON to parse this, I have created a whole app which normally would rely on 6 or so XML's use one JSON file. I would be happy to help with the JSON parsing. JSON is also a lot easier to read, parse, and create

Comment: thanks for suggestion, so could you please tell me the link from where i can get this tutorial or complete source code, becuase i have never worked on json earlier, but i always want to learn new things and implement them in my program...please help like you are doing for last one hour.....

Comment: i have send you an email, thanks a lot...to support really

Comment: If this answer helped you mark it as correct to help other users find it